# In dass-Sätzen Haupt- und Nebensatz vertauschen

Tags: grammar

Heute lerne ich die dass-Sätze, und ich habe diese Beispiele:

> Wussten Sie schon, dass wir einen neuen Chef bekommen?
>
> Ich weiß nicht, dass Viktor zu Hause war.

Kann ich diese dass-Sätze folgenderweise schreiben?

> Dass wir einen neuen Chef bekommen, wussten Sie schon?
>
> Dass Viktor zu Hause war, weiß ich nicht.

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rein grammatikalisch ist der zweite Satz in Ordnung. Nur inhaltlich gibt es ein Problem - dazu aber später, weil es mit der eigentlichen Frage nichts zu tun hat.

Das erste Beispiel ist hingegen ein Fragesatz. Hier lässt sich die Reihenfolge nicht so ohne weiteres umkehren. Möglich wären:

> Dass wir einen neuen Chef bekommen – wussten Sie das schon?

oder

> Wir bekommen einen neuen Chef – wussten Sie das schon?

Die erste Variante setzt voraus, dass dem Gegenüber die Nachricht schon bekannt ist. Die zweite Variante überbringt die Nachricht und fragt, ob sie dem Gegenüber schon bekannt war. In

> Wussten Sie schon, dass wir einen neuen Chef bekommen?

muss man diese Unterscheidung durch Tonfall und Betonung treffen.

Kurioserweise ist auch Dein Vorschlag

> Dass wir einen neuen Chef bekommen, wussten Sie schon?

eine korrekte Umstellung, aber sie gehört zur Frage

> Sie wussten schon, dass wir einen neuen Chef bekommen?

in der sich der Fragesteller darüber erstaunt zeigt, dass sein Gegenüber die Nachricht offenbar schon kannte.

---

Nun nochmal zum zweiten Satz. Der ist von seiner Aussage her ein Widerspruch in sich. Entweder ist sich der Sprecher zum Zeitpunkt der Aussage sicher, dass "er" zu Hause war - dann kann er aber nicht behaupten, dass er es nicht weiß. Er könnte es nur noch für die Vergangenheit verneinen ("Ich wusste nicht, dass..."). Oder er ist sich nicht sicher, dann müsste er das aber mit "ob" kennzeichnen ("Ich weiß nicht, ob..."). Das Problem besteht unabhängig davon, ob Du mit dem Haupt- oder dem Nebensatz anfängst, denn die Aussage ändert sich dadurch ja nicht. Es ist vielmehr in der Ich-Form des Satzes begründet. Wenn über eine dritte Person eine Aussage getroffen wird, verschwindet der Widerspruch:

> Thomas weiß nicht, dass Viktor zu Hause war.

ist völlig in Ordnung.

Comment: das ist mehr interessant! Vielen Danke! :)

Comment: Ich verstehe den Teil in der Klammer am Anfang nicht. "Ich weiß nicht, dass er zu Hause war" == "Dass er zu Hause war,..." Die Aussagen sind völlig identisch. Das ist der Sinn eines Nebensatzes. Er ist nicht anders als ein Pronomen. Ausserdem ist die Aussage an sich völlig ok. Es gibt einen Fakt "Er war zu Hause" und dieser Fakt ist mir nicht bekannt. Kein Grund für "ob"

Comment: @Emanuel "Ich weiß nicht, dass er zu Hause war" ist für mich ein Widerspruch in sich. Entweder ist sich der Sprecher zum Zeitpunkt der Aussage sicher, dass "er" zu Hause war - dann könnte er diese Kenntnis aber nur noch für die Vergangenheit verneinen ("Ich wußte nicht, dass.."). Oder er ist sich nicht sicher, dann müsste er das aber mit "ob" kennzeichnen ("Ich weiß nicht, ob..."). Darauf wollte ich hinweisen. Mit der eigentlichen Frage hat das nichts zu tun, denn die Aussage ändert sich durch die Reihenfolge natürlich nicht, und darauf wollte ich am Anfang der Klammer auch hinweisen.

Comment: @Matthias.. ah, jetzt verstehe ich das Problem. Das eigentliche Problem ist aber das "ich", nicht die Zeiten. Mit "THomas" würde es wunderbar funktionieren. Vielleicht solltest du das noch einfügen, sonst denken einige wissen im Präsens geht nicht mit Vergangenheit

Comment: @Emanuel Guter Punkt. Ich habe das nochmal neu formuliert und ans Ende geschoben, weil das ja nur eine Randbemerkung ist.

Comment: Der Satz könnte zum Beispiel in einer im Präsenz geschriebenen Erzählung vorkommen.

Comment: "Dass wir einen neuen Chef bekommen, wussten Sie schon?" ist sehr wohl eine korrekte Umstellung, wenn man wie im Original *wussten* betont und nicht *schon*. Sie ist halt nur mehrdeutig, weil nachgestellte Hauptsätze immer invertiert werden und das Original deshalb auch sein könnte "Sie wussten schon, dass wir einen neuen Chef bekommen?" Mit Betonung auf *wussten* ist die Unterstellung der Antwort *Ja* nicht so stark, dass ich das als falsch werten würde.

Comment: Der zweite Satz wäre ganz natürlich in einer polizeilichen Vernehmung: "Woher wissen Sie denn überhaupt, dass Viktor zu Hause war, wenn Sie ihn doch den ganzen Tag nicht gesehen haben?" - "Ich weiß nicht, dass Viktor zu Hause war. Ich gehe aber davon aus, weil Sie es vorhin gesagt haben." / "Dass Viktor zu Hause war, weiß ich nicht. Ich weiß nur, dass er nicht bei der Arbeit war."